# What is the difference between different ways to create a function inside javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the difference between **method1** and **method2** ?

```
let myObject = {
     method1: function(x){
         console.log(...);
     },
     method2(x){
         console.log(...);
     }
}
```

Comment: `method2` is actually typescript. not javascript

Comment: You're asking the difference between something that is syntactically correct and incorrect. *EDIT: It seems I'm wrong, thans for correcting me.*

Comment: @Glubus, Jamiec: it IS valid es2015 (if we add that comma): https://monosnap.com/file/tpWRqrOSNB2q4sjwm7HbVCLWOX7sCU.png

Comment: Semantically, these methods are equivalent, and contrary to the claims above, this is valid JavaScript ES6 except for the missing comma between the two function bodies within the object literal.

Comment: To help better understand your need for asking - why do you think there _is_ a difference?

Comment: @JamesThorpe just needed to know if there can be a difference in any way like binding or scope or anything else

Comment: @YouMa there is no difference in binding or scope. Object literal member methods are just like regular ES5 syntax functions assigned to object keys, as in `method1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. `method2` is just a shorthand syntax introduced in ES6.

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced. It is a shorthand for a function assigned to the method's name.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference here, as stated in the comments.

It's just a matter of "how do you want to write it".

But if you're starting a project, you should choose one way and stick to it, and if the project is already started, try to stick to the way the most used. It'll greatly help to read the code easily.

Also, if it's about scope or binding, you should have a look here :

http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html